# insert large data into SQLITE3 i-phone

Tags: sqlite

```
INSERT INTO `words` (`id`, `word`) VALUES
(1, 'aa'),
(2, 'aah'),
(3, 'aal'),
(4, 'aalii'),
(5, 'aardvark'),
(6, 'aardvarks'),
(7, 'aardwolf'),
(8, 'aardwolves'),
(9, 'aargh'),
(10, 'aarrghh'),
(11, 'aasvogel'),
(12, 'aasvogels'),
(13, 'ab'),
(14, 'aba'),
(15, 'abaca'),
(16, 'abacas'),
(17, 'abaci'),
(18, 'aback'),
(19, 'abacus'),
(20, 'abacuses'),
(21, 'abaft'),
(22, 'abalone'),
(23, 'abalones'),
(24, 'abampere'),
(25, 'abamperes'),
(26, 'abandon'),
(27, 'abandoned'),
(28, 'abandonee'),
(29, 'abandoning'),
(30, 'abandons'),
(31, 'abase'),
(32, 'abased'),
(33, 'abasement'),
(34, 'abases'),
(35, 'abash'),
(36, 'abashed'),
(37, 'abashes'),
(38, 'abashing'),
(39, 'abashment'),
(40, 'abashments'),
(41, 'abasing'),
(42, 'abatable'),
(43, 'abate'),
(44, 'abated'),
(45, 'abatement'),
(46, 'abatements'),
(47, 'abates'),
(48, 'abating'),
(49, 'abatis'),
(50, 'abator'),
(51, 'abators'),
(52, 'abattis'),
(53, 'abattises'),
(54, 'abattoir'),
(55, 'abattoirs'),
(56, 'abaxial'),
(57, 'abba'),
(58, 'abbacies'),
(59, 'abbacy'),
(60, 'abbas'),
(61, 'abbatial'),
(62, 'abbe'),
(63, 'abbes'),
(64, 'abbess'),
(65, 'abbesses'),
(66, 'abbey'),
(67, 'abbeys'),
(68, 'abbot'),
(69, 'abbotcy'),
(70, 'abbots'),
(71, 'abbreviate'),
(72, 'abdicate'),
(73, 'abdicated'),
(74, 'abdicates'),
(75, 'abdicating'),
(76, 'abdication'),
(77, 'abdicator'),
(78, 'abdicators'),
(79, 'abdomen'),
(80, 'abdomens'),
(81, 'abdominal'),
(82, 'abdominals'),
(83, 'abduce'),
(84, 'abduced'),
(85, 'abduces'),
(86, 'abducing'),
(87, 'abduct'),
(88, 'abducted'),
(89, 'abductee'),
(90, 'abductees'),
(91, 'abducting'),
(92, 'abduction'),
(93, 'abductions'),
(94, 'abductor'),
(95, 'abductors'),
(96, 'abducts'),
(97, 'abeam'),
(98, 'abear'),
(99, 'abearing'),
(100, 'abears'),
(101, 'abed'),
(102, 'abeigh'),
(103, 'abele'),
(104, 'abeles'),
(105, 'abelia'),
(106, 'aberdevine'),
(107, 'aberrance'),
(108, 'aberrancy'),
(109, 'aberrant'),
(110, 'aberrate'),
(111, 'aberrated'),
(112, 'aberrates'),
(113, 'aberrating'),
(114, 'aberration'),
(115, 'abessive'),
(116, 'abet'),
(117, 'abetment'),
(118, 'abetments'),
(119, 'abets'),
(120, 'abettal'),
(121, 'abettals'),
(122, 'abetted'),
(123, 'abetter'),
(124, 'abetters'),
(125, 'abetting'),
(126, 'abettor'),
(127, 'abettors'),
(128, 'abeyance'),
(129, 'abeyances'),
(130, 'abeyancies'),
(131, 'abeyancy'),
(132, 'abeyant'),
(133, 'abhor'),
(134, 'abhorred'),
(135, 'abhorrence'),
(136, 'abhorrency'),
(137, 'abhorrent'),
(138, 'abhorrer'),
(139, 'abhorrers'),
(140, 'abhorring'),
(141, 'abhors'),
(142, 'abidance'),
(143, 'abidances'),
(144, 'abidden'),
(145, 'abide'),
(146, 'abided'),
(147, 'abides'),
(148, 'abiding'),
(149, 'abidingly'),
(150, 'abidings'),
(151, 'abies'),
(152, 'abieses'),
(153, 'abigail'),
(154, 'abigails'),
(155, 'abilities'),
(156, 'ability'),
(157, 'abiogenist'),
(158, 'abioses'),
(159, 'abiosis'),
(160, 'abiotic'),
(161, 'abject'),
(162, 'abjected'),
(163, 'abjecting'),
(164, 'abjection'),
(165, 'abjections'),
(166, 'abjectly'),
(167, 'abjectness'),
(168, 'abjects'),
(169, 'abjoint'),
(170, 'abjointed'),
(171, 'abjointing'),
(172, 'abjoints'),
(173, 'abjunction'),
(174, 'abjuration'),
(175, 'abjure'),
(176, 'abjured'),
(177, 'abjurer'),
(178, 'abjurers'),
(179, 'abjures'),
(180, 'abjuring'),
(181, 'ablate'),
(182, 'ablated'),
(183, 'ablates'),
(184, 'ablating'),
(185, 'ablation'),
(186, 'ablations'),
(187, 'ablatival'),
(188, 'ablative'),
(189, 'ablatives'),
(190, 'ablator'),
(191, 'ablators'),
(192, 'ablaut'),
(193, 'ablauts'),
(194, 'ablaze'),
(195, 'able'),
(196, 'abler'),
(197, 'ablest'),
(198, 'ablet'),
(199, 'ablets'),
(200, 'ablins'),
(201, 'abloom'),
(202, 'ablow'),
(203, 'ablush'),
(204, 'ablution'),
(205, 'ablutions'),
(206, 'ablutomane'),
(207, 'ably'),
(208, 'abnegate'),
(209, 'abnegated'),
(210, 'abnegates'),
(211, 'abnegating'),
(212, 'abnegation'),
(213, 'abnegator'),
(214, 'abnegators'),
(215, 'abnormal'),
(216, 'abnormally'),
(217, 'abnormity'),
(218, 'abnormous'),
(219, 'aboard'),
(220, 'abode'),
(221, 'abodement'),
(222, 'abodes'),
(223, 'aboideau'),
(224, 'aboideaus'),
(225, 'aboideaux'),
(226, 'aboil'),
(227, 'aboiteau'),
(228, 'aboiteaus'),
(229, 'aboiteaux'),
(230, 'abolish'),
(231, 'abolished'),
(232, 'abolisher'),
(233, 'abolishers'),
(234, 'abolishes'),
(235, 'abolishing'),
(236, 'abolition'),
(237, 'abolitions'),
(238, 'abolla'),
(239, 'abollae'),
(240, 'abollas'),
(241, 'abomasa'),
(242, 'abomasal'),
(243, 'abomasum'),
(244, 'abomasus'),
(245, 'abomasuses'),
(246, 'abominable'),
(247, 'abominably'),
(248, 'abominate'),
(249, 'abominated'),
(250, 'abominates'),
(251, 'abominator'),
(252, 'abondance'),
(253, 'abondances'),
(254, 'aboral'),
(255, 'abord'),
(256, 'aborded'),
(257, 'abording'),
(258, 'abords'),
(259, 'abore'),
(260, 'aboriginal'),
(261, 'aborigine'),
(262, 'aborigines'),
(263, 'aborne'),
(264, 'aborning'),
(265, 'abort'),
(266, 'aborted'),
(267, 'aborticide'),
(268, 'aborting'),
(269, 'abortion'),
(270, 'abortional'),
(271, 'abortions'),
(272, 'abortive'),
(273, 'abortively'),
(274, 'aborts'),
(275, 'abought'),
(276, 'aboulia'),
(277, 'abound'),
(278, 'abounded'),
(279, 'abounding'),
(280, 'abounds'),
(281, 'about'),
(282, 'abouts'),
(283, 'above'),
(284, 'abradant'),
(285, 'abradants'),
(286, 'abrade'),
(287, 'abraded'),
(288, 'abrader'),
(289, 'abraders'),
(290, 'abrades'),
(291, 'abrading'),
(292, 'abraid'),
(293, 'abraided'),
(294, 'abraiding'),
(295, 'abraids'),
(296, 'abram'),
(297, 'abranchial'),
(298, 'abrasion'),
(299, 'abrasions'),
(300, 'abrasive'),
(301, 'abrasively'),
(302, 'abrasives'),
(303, 'abraxas'),
(304, 'abraxases'),
(305, 'abray'),
(306, 'abrazo'),
(307, 'abrazos'),
(308, 'abreact'),
(309, 'abreacted'),
(310, 'abreacting'),
(311, 'abreaction'),
(312, 'abreacts'),
(313, 'abreast'),
(314, 'abrege'),
(315, 'abricock'),
(316, 'abridge'),
(317, 'abridged'),
(318, 'abridger'),
(319, 'abridgers'),
(320, 'abridges'),
(321, 'abridging'),
(322, 'abridgment'),
(323, 'abrim'),
(324, 'abrin'),
(325, 'abroach'),
(326, 'abroad'),
(327, 'abrogate'),
(328, 'abrogated'),
(329, 'abrogates'),
(330, 'abrogating'),
(331, 'abrogation'),
(332, 'abrogative'),
(333, 'abrogator'),
(334, 'abrogators'),
(335, 'abrupt'),
(336, 'abrupter'),
(337, 'abruptest'),
(338, 'abruption'),
(339, 'abruptions'),
(340, 'abruptly'),
(341, 'abruptness'),
(342, 'abscess'),
(343, 'abscessed'),
(344, 'abscesses'),
(345, 'abscind'),
(346, 'abscinded'),
(347, 'abscinding'),
(348, 'abscinds'),
(349, 'abscise'),
(350, 'abscised'),
(351, 'abscises'),
(352, 'abscisin'),
(353, 'abscising'),
(354, 'abscisins'),
(355, 'absciss'),
(356, 'abscissa'),
(357, 'abscissae'),
(358, 'abscissas'),
(359, 'abscisse'),
(360, 'abscisses'),
(361, 'abscissin'),
(362, 'abscissins'),
(363, 'abscission'),
(364, 'abscond'),
(365, 'absconded'),
(366, 'absconder'),
(367, 'absconders'),
(368, 'absconding'),
(369, 'absconds'),
(370, 'abseil'),
(371, 'abseiled'),
(372, 'abseiling'),
(373, 'abseilings'),
(374, 'abseils'),
(375, 'absence'),
(376, 'absences'),
(377, 'absent'),
(378, 'absented'),
(379, 'absentee'),
(380, 'absentees'),
(381, 'absenting'),
(382, 'absently'),
(383, 'absents'),
(384, 'absey'),
(385, 'absinth'),
(386, 'absinthe'),
(387, 'absinthes'),
(388, 'absinthism'),
(389, 'absinths'),
(390, 'absit'),
(391, 'absolute'),
(392, 'absolutely'),
(393, 'absolution'),
(394, 'absolutism'),
(395, 'absolutist'),
(396, 'absolutory'),
(397, 'absolve'),
(398, 'absolved'),
(399, 'absolver'),
(400, 'absolvers'),
(401, 'absolves'),
(402, 'absolving'),
(403, 'absolvitor'),
(404, 'absonant'),
(405, 'absorb'),
(406, 'absorbable'),
(407, 'absorbed'),
(408, 'absorbedly'),
(409, 'absorbency'),
(410, 'absorbent'),
(411, 'absorbents'),
(412, 'absorber'),
(413, 'absorbers'),
(414, 'absorbing'),
(415, 'absorbs'),
(416, 'absorption'),
(417, 'absorptive'),
(418, 'abstain'),
(419, 'abstained'),
(420, 'abstainer'),
(421, 'abstainers'),
(422, 'abstaining'),
(423, 'abstains'),
(424, 'abstemious'),
(425, 'abstention'),
(426, 'absterge'),
(427, 'absterged'),
(428, 'abstergent'),
(429, 'absterges'),
(430, 'absterging'),
(431, 'abstersion'),
(432, 'abstersive'),
(433, 'abstinence'),
(434, 'abstinency'),
(435, 'abstinent'),
(436, 'abstract'),
(437, 'abstracted'),
(438, 'abstracter'),
(439, 'abstractly'),
(440, 'abstractor'),
(441, 'abstracts'),
(442, 'abstrict'),
(443, 'abstricted'),
(444, 'abstricts'),
(445, 'abstruse'),
(446, 'abstrusely'),
(447, 'abstruser'),
(448, 'abstrusest'),
(449, 'absurd'),
(450, 'absurder'),
(451, 'absurdest'),
(452, 'absurdism'),
(453, 'absurdist'),
(454, 'absurdists'),
(455, 'absurdity'),
(456, 'absurdly'),
(457, 'absurdness'),
(458, 'abulia'),
(459, 'abuna'),
(460, 'abunas'),
(461, 'abundance'),
(462, 'abundances'),
(463, 'abundancy'),
(464, 'abundant'),
(465, 'abundantly'),
(466, 'abune'),
(467, 'aburst'),
(468, 'abusage'),
(469, 'abusages'),
(470, 'abuse'),
(471, 'abused'),
(472, 'abuser'),
(473, 'abusers'),
(474, 'abuses'),
(475, 'abusing'),
(476, 'abusion'),
(477, 'abusions'),
(478, 'abusive'),
(479, 'abusively'),
(480, 'abut'),
(481, 'abutilon'),
(482, 'abutilons'),
(483, 'abutment'),
(484, 'abutments'),
(485, 'abuts'),
(486, 'abuttal'),
(487, 'abuttals'),
(488, 'abutted'),
(489, 'abutter'),
(490, 'abutters'),
(491, 'abutting'),
(492, 'abuzz'),
(493, 'abvolt'),
(494, 'abvolts'),
(495, 'aby'),
(496, 'abye'),
(497, 'abyeing'),
(498, 'abyes'),
(499, 'abying'),
(500, 'abysm'),
(501, 'abysmal'),
(502, 'abysmally'),
(503, 'abysms'),
(504, 'abyss'),
(505, 'abyssal'),
(506, 'abysses'),
(507, 'acacia'),
(508, 'acacias'),
(509, 'academe'),
(510, 'academes'),
(511, 'academia'),
(512, 'academic'),
(513, 'academical'),
(514, 'academics'),
(515, 'academies'),
(516, 'academism'),
(517, 'academist'),
(518, 'academists'),
(519, 'academy'),
(520, 'acajou'),
(521, 'acajous'),
(522, 'acaleph'),
(523, 'acalephan'),
(524, 'acalephans'),
(525, 'acalephas'),
(526, 'acalephe'),
(527, 'acalephes'),
(528, 'acalephs'),
(529, 'acanaceous'),
(530, 'acanth'),
(531, 'acantha'),
(532, 'acanthas'),
(533, 'acanthin'),
(534, 'acanthine'),
(535, 'acanthoid'),
(536, 'acanthous'),
(537, 'acanths'),
(538, 'acanthus'),
(539, 'acanthuses'),
(540, 'acapnia'),
(541, 'acari'),
(542, 'acarian'),
(543, 'acariasis'),
(544, 'acaricide'),
(545, 'acaricides'),
(546, 'acarid'),
(547, 'acaridan'),
(548, 'acaridans'),
(549, 'acaridean'),
(550, 'acarideans'),
(551, 'acarids'),
(552, 'acarine'),
(553, 'acaroid'),
(554, 'acarology'),
(555, 'acarpelous'),
(556, 'acarpous'),
(557, 'acarus'),
(558, 'acatalepsy'),
(559, 'acater'),
(560, 'acaters'),
(561, 'acates'),
(562, 'acatour'),
(563, 'acatours'),
(564, 'acaudal'),
(565, 'acaudate'),
(566, 'acauline'),
(567, 'acaulose'),
(568, 'accable'),
(569, 'accede'),
(570, 'acceded'),
(571, 'accedence'),
(572, 'accedences'),
(573, 'acceder'),
(574, 'acceders'),
(575, 'accedes'),
(576, 'acceding'),
(577, 'accelerant'),
(578, 'accelerate'),
(579, 'accend'),
(580, 'accension'),
(581, 'accensions'),
(582, 'accent'),
(583, 'accented'),
(584, 'accenting'),
(585, 'accentor'),
(586, 'accentors'),
(587, 'accents'),
(588, 'accentual'),
(589, 'accentuate'),
(590, 'accept'),
(591, 'acceptable'),
(592, 'acceptably'),
(593, 'acceptance'),
(594, 'acceptancy'),
(595, 'acceptant'),
(596, 'acceptants'),
(597, 'accepted'),
(598, 'acceptedly'),
(599, 'accepter'),
(600, 'accepters'),
(601, 'accepting'),
(602, 'acceptive'),
(603, 'acceptor'),
(604, 'acceptors'),
(605, 'accepts'),
(606, 'access'),
(607, 'accessary'),
(608, 'accessed'),
(609, 'accesses'),
(610, 'accessible'),
(611, 'accessibly'),
(612, 'accessing'),
(613, 'accession'),
(614, 'accessions'),
(615, 'accessory'),
(616, 'accidence'),
(617, 'accident'),
(618, 'accidental'),
(619, 'accidented'),
(620, 'accidents'),
(621, 'accidie'),
(622, 'accinge'),
(623, 'accinged'),
(624, 'accinges'),
(625, 'accinging'),
(626, 'accipiter'),
(627, 'accipiters'),
(628, 'accite'),
(629, 'accited'),
(630, 'accites'),
(631, 'acciting'),
(632, 'acclaim'),
(633, 'acclaimed'),
(634, 'acclaiming'),
(635, 'acclaims'),
(636, 'acclimate'),
(637, 'acclimated'),
(638, 'acclimates'),
(639, 'acclivity'),
(640, 'acclivous'),
(641, 'accloy'),
(642, 'accoast'),
(643, 'accoasted'),
(644, 'accoasting'),
(645, 'accoasts'),
(646, 'accoil'),
(647, 'accoils'),
(648, 'accolade'),
(649, 'accolades'),
(650, 'accompany'),
(651, 'accomplice'),
(652, 'accomplish'),
(653, 'accompt'),
(654, 'accomptant'),
(655, 'accompted'),
(656, 'accompting'),
(657, 'accompts'),
(658, 'accorage'),
(659, 'accord'),
(660, 'accordable'),
(661, 'accordance'),
(662, 'accordancy'),
(663, 'accordant'),
(664, 'accorded'),
(665, 'accorder'),
(666, 'accorders'),
(667, 'according'),
(668, 'accordion'),
(669, 'accordions'),
(670, 'accords'),
(671, 'accost'),
(672, 'accostable'),
(673, 'accosted'),
(674, 'accosting'),
(675, 'accosts'),
(676, 'accoucheur'),
(677, 'account'),
(678, 'accountant'),
(679, 'accounted'),
(680, 'accounting'),
(681, 'accounts'),
(682, 'accourage'),
(683, 'accourt'),
(684, 'accourted'),
(685, 'accourting'),
(686, 'accourts'),
(687, 'accouter'),
(688, 'accoutered'),
(689, 'accouters'),
(690, 'accoutre'),
(691, 'accoutred'),
(692, 'accoutres'),
(693, 'accoutring'),
(694, 'accoy'),
(695, 'accredit'),
(696, 'accredited'),
(697, 'accredits'),
(698, 'accrescent'),
(699, 'accrete'),
(700, 'accreted'),
(701, 'accretes'),
(702, 'accreting'),
(703, 'accretion'),
(704, 'accretions'),
(705, 'accretive'),
(706, 'accrual'),
(707, 'accruals'),
(708, 'accrue'),
(709, 'accrued'),
(710, 'accrues'),
(711, 'accruing'),
(712, 'accubation'),
(713, 'accultural'),
(714, 'accumbency'),
(715, 'accumbent'),
(716, 'accumulate'),
(717, 'accuracies'),
(718, 'accuracy'),
(719, 'accurate'),
(720, 'accurately'),
(721, 'accurse'),
(722, 'accursed'),
(723, 'accursedly'),
(724, 'accurses'),
(725, 'accursing'),
(726, 'accurst'),
(727, 'accusable'),
(728, 'accusal'),
(729, 'accusals'),
(730, 'accusation'),
(731, 'accusative'),
(732, 'accusatory'),
(733, 'accuse'),
(734, 'accused'),
(735, 'accuser'),
(736, 'accusers'),
(737, 'accuses'),
(738, 'accusing'),
(739, 'accusingly'),
(740, 'accustom'),
(741, 'accustomed'),
(742, 'accustoms'),
(743, 'ace'),
(744, 'aced'),
(745, 'acedia'),
(746, 'acellular'),
(747, 'acephalous'),
(748, 'aceraceous'),
(749, 'acerate'),
(750, 'acerb'),
(751, 'acerbate'),
(752, 'acerbated'),
(753, 'acerbates'),
(754, 'acerbating'),
(755, 'acerbic'),
(756, 'acerbities'),
(757, 'acerbity'),
(758, 'acerose'),
(759, 'acerous'),
(760, 'acers'),
(761, 'acervate'),
(762, 'acervately'),
(763, 'acervation'),
(764, 'aces'),
(765, 'acescence'),
(766, 'acescency'),
(767, 'acescent'),
(768, 'acetabula'),
(769, 'acetabular'),
(770, 'acetabulum'),
(771, 'acetal'),
(772, 'acetals'),
(773, 'acetamide'),
(774, 'acetate'),
(775, 'acetates'),
(776, 'acetic'),
(777, 'acetified'),
(778, 'acetifies'),
(779, 'acetify'),
(780, 'acetifying'),
(781, 'acetone'),
(782, 'acetones'),
(783, 'acetose'),
(784, 'acetous'),
(785, 'acetyl'),
(786, 'acetylene'),
(787, 'achage'),
(788, 'achages'),
(789, 'acharne'),
(790, 'ache'),
(791, 'ached'),
(792, 'achene'),
(793, 'achenes'),
(794, 'achenial'),
(795, 'achenium'),
(796, 'acheniums'),
(797, 'aches'),
(798, 'achier'),
(799, 'achiest'),
(800, 'achievable'),
(801, 'achieve'),
(802, 'achieved'),
(803, 'achiever'),
(804, 'achievers'),
(805, 'achieves'),
(806, 'achieving'),
(807, 'achillea'),
(808, 'achilleas'),
(809, 'achimenes'),
(810, 'aching'),
(811, 'achingly'),
(812, 'achings'),
(813, 'achkan'),
(814, 'achkans'),
(815, 'achromat'),
(816, 'achromatic'),
(817, 'achromatin'),
(818, 'achromats'),
(819, 'achy'),
(820, 'acicular'),
(821, 'aciculate'),
(822, 'aciculated'),
(823, 'acid'),
(824, 'acidhead'),
(825, 'acidheads'),
(826, 'acidic'),
(827, 'acidified'),
(828, 'acidifier'),
(829, 'acidifiers'),
(830, 'acidifies'),
(831, 'acidify'),
(832, 'acidifying'),
(833, 'acidimeter'),
(834, 'acidimetry'),
(835, 'acidity'),
(836, 'acidly'),
(837, 'acidness'),
(838, 'acidosis'),
(839, 'acids'),
(840, 'acidulate'),
(841, 'acidulated'),
(842, 'acidulates'),
(843, 'acidulent'),
(844, 'acidulous'),
(845, 'acierage'),
(846, 'acierate'),
(847, 'acierated'),
(848, 'acierates'),
(849, 'acierating'),
(850, 'acieration'),
(851, 'aciform'),
(852, 'acinaceous'),
(853, 'acing'),
(854, 'acini'),
(855, 'aciniform'),
(856, 'acinose'),
(857, 'acinous'),
(858, 'acinus'),
(859, 'ackee'),
(860, 'ackees'),
(861, 'acknow'),
(862, 'aclinic'),
(863, 'acme'),
(864, 'acmes'),
(865, 'acmite'),
(866, 'acmites'),
(867, 'acne'),
(868, 'acock'),
(869, 'acoemeti'),
(870, 'acold'),
(871, 'acoluthic'),
(872, 'acolyte'),
(873, 'acolytes'),
(874, 'aconite'),
(875, 'aconites'),
(876, 'aconitic'),
(877, 'aconitine'),
(878, 'aconitum'),
(879, 'aconitums'),
(880, 'acorn'),
(881, 'acorned'),
(882, 'acorns'),
(883, 'acosmism'),
(884, 'acosmist'),
(885, 'acosmists'),
(886, 'acotyledon'),
(887, 'acouchi'),
(888, 'acouchies'),
(889, 'acouchy'),
(890, 'acoustic'),
(891, 'acoustical'),
(892, 'acoustics'),
(893, 'acquaint'),
(894, 'acquainted'),
(895, 'acquaints'),
(896, 'acquest'),
(897, 'acquests'),
(898, 'acquiesce'),
(899, 'acquiesced'),
(900, 'acquiesces'),
(901, 'acquight'),
(902, 'acquighted'),
(903, 'acquights'),
(904, 'acquirable'),
(905, 'acquire'),
(906, 'acquired'),
(907, 'acquires'),
(908, 'acquiring'),
(909, 'acquist'),
(910, 'acquit'),
(911, 'acquite'),
(912, 'acquited'),
(913, 'acquites'),
(914, 'acquiting'),
(915, 'acquitment'),
(916, 'acquits'),
(917, 'acquittal'),
(918, 'acquittals'),
(919, 'acquitted'),
(920, 'acquitting'),
(921, 'acrawl'),
(922, 'acre'),
(923, 'acreage'),
(924, 'acred'),
(925, 'acres'),
(926, 'acrid'),
(927, 'acridine'),
(928, 'acridity'),
(929, 'acriflavin'),
(930, 'acrimony'),
(931, 'acroamatic'),
(932, 'acrobat'),
(933, 'acrobatic'),
(934, 'acrobatics'),
(935, 'acrobatism'),
(936, 'acrobats'),
(937, 'acrogen'),
(938, 'acrogenic'),
(939, 'acrogenous'),
(940, 'acrogens'),
(941, 'acrolein'),
(942, 'acrolith'),
(943, 'acrolithic'),
(944, 'acroliths'),
(945, 'acromegaly'),
(946, 'acromia'),
(947, 'acromial'),
(948, 'acromion'),
(949, 'acronical'),
(950, 'acronycal'),
(951, 'acronychal'),
(952, 'acronym'),
(953, 'acronymic'),
(954, 'acronymous'),
(955, 'acronyms'),
(956, 'acropetal'),
(957, 'acrophobia'),
(958, 'acrophonic'),
(959, 'acrophony'),
(960, 'acropolis'),
(961, 'acrosome'),
(962, 'acrosomes'),
(963, 'acrospire'),
(964, 'acrospires'),
(965, 'across'),
(966, 'acrostic'),
(967, 'acrostics'),
(968, 'acroter'),
(969, 'acroteria'),
(970, 'acroterial'),
(971, 'acroterion'),
(972, 'acroterium'),
(973, 'acroters'),
(974, 'acrotism'),
(975, 'acrylic'),
(976, 'acrylics'),
(977, 'act'),
(978, 'acta'),
(979, 'actability'),
(980, 'actable'),
(981, 'acted'),
(982, 'actin'),
(983, 'actinal'),
(984, 'actinally'),
(985, 'acting'),
(986, 'actings'),
(987, 'actinia'),
(988, 'actiniae'),
(989, 'actinian'),
(990, 'actinians'),
(991, 'actinias'),
(992, 'actinic'),
(993, 'actinide'),
(994, 'actinides'),
(995, 'actinism'),
(996, 'actinium'),
(997, 'actinoid'),
(998, 'actinoids'),
(999, 'actinolite'),
(1000, 'actinon'),
(1001, 'action'),
(1002, 'actionable'),
(1003, 'actionably'),
(1004, 'actioned'),
(1005, 'actioning'),
(1006, 'actions'),
(1007, 'activate'),
(1008, 'activated'),
(1009, 'activates'),
(1010, 'activating'),
(1011, 'activation'),
(1012, 'activator'),
(1013, 'activators'),
(1014, 'active'),
(1015, 'actively'),
(1016, 'activeness'),
(1017, 'activism'),
(1018, 'activist'),
(1019, 'activists'),
(1020, 'activities'),
(1021, 'activity'),
(1022, 'acton'),
(1023, 'actons'),
(1024, 'actor'),
(1025, 'actors'),
(1026, 'actress'),
(1027, 'actresses'),
(1028, 'actressy'),
(1029, 'acts'),
(1030, 'actual'),
(1031, 'actualise'),
(1032, 'actualised'),
(1033, 'actualises'),
(1034, 'actualist'),
(1035, 'actualists'),
(1036, 'actuality'),
(1037, 'actualize'),
(1038, 'actualized'),
(1039, 'actualizes'),
(1040, 'actually'),
(1041, 'actuarial'),
(1042, 'actuaries'),
(1043, 'actuary'),
(1044, 'actuate'),
(1045, 'actuated'),
(1046, 'actuates'),
(1047, 'actuating'),
(1048, 'actuation'),
(1049, 'actuations'),
(1050, 'actuator'),
(1051, 'actuators'),
(1052, 'acture'),
(1053, 'acuity'),
(1054, 'aculeate'),
(1055, 'aculeated'),
(1056, 'aculeus'),
(1057, 'acumen'),
(1058, 'acumens'),
(1059, 'acuminate'),
(1060, 'acuminated'),
(1061, 'acuminates'),
(1062, 'acuminous'),
(1063, 'acupoint'),
(1064, 'acupoints'),
(1065, 'acushla'),
(1066, 'acushlas'),
(1067, 'acute'),
(1068, 'acutely'),
(1069, 'acuteness'),
(1070, 'acuter'),
(1071, 'acutest'),
(1072, 'acyclic'),
(1073, 'acyclovir'),
(1074, 'acyl'),
(1075, 'ad'),
(1076, 'adactylous'),
(1077, 'adage'),
(1078, 'adages'),
(1079, 'adagio'),
(1080, 'adagios'),
(1081, 'adamant'),
(1082, 'adamantean'),
(1083, 'adamantine'),
(1084, 'adamantly'),
(1085, 'adamants'),
(1086, 'adapt'),
(1087, 'adaptable'),
(1088, 'adaptation'),
(1089, 'adaptative'),
(1090, 'adapted'),
(1091, 'adapter'),
(1092, 'adapters'),
(1093, 'adapting'),
(1094, 'adaption'),
(1095, 'adaptions'),
(1096, 'adaptive'),
(1097, 'adaptively'),
(1098, 'adaptor'),
(1099, 'adaptors'),
(1100, 'adapts'),
(1101, 'adaw'),
(1102, 'adaxial'),
(1103, 'adays'),
(1104, 'add'),
(1105, 'addax'),
(1106, 'addaxes'),
(1107, 'addebted'),
(1108, 'added'),
(1109, 'addeem'),
(1110, 'addend'),
(1111, 'addenda'),
(1112, 'addends'),
(1113, 'addendum'),
(1114, 'adder'),
(1115, 'adders'),
(1116, 'adderstone'),
(1117, 'adderwort'),
(1118, 'adderworts'),
(1119, 'addict'),
(1120, 'addicted'),
(1121, 'addicting'),
(1122, 'addiction'),
(1123, 'addictions'),
(1124, 'addictive'),
(1125, 'addicts'),
(1126, 'adding'),
(1127, 'addio'),
(1128, 'addios'),
(1129, 'additament'),
(1130, 'addition'),
(1131, 'additional'),
(1132, 'additions'),
(1133, 'additive'),
(1134, 'additively'),
(1135, 'additives'),
(1136, 'addle'),
(1137, 'addled'),
(1138, 'addlement'),
(1139, 'addles'),
(1140, 'addling'),
(1141, 'addoom'),
(1142, 'addorsed'),
(1143, 'address'),
(1144, 'addressed'),
(1145, 'addressee'),
(1146, 'addressees'),
(1147, 'addresser'),
(1148, 'addressers'),
(1149, 'addresses'),
(1150, 'addressing'),
(1151, 'addressor'),
(1152, 'addressors'),
(1153, 'addrest'),
(1154, 'adds'),
(1155, 'adduce'),
(1156, 'adduced'),
(1157, 'adducent'),
(1158, 'adducer'),
(1159, 'adducers'),
(1160, 'adduces'),
(1161, 'adducible'),
(1162, 'adducing'),
(1163, 'adduct'),
(1164, 'adducted'),
(1165, 'adducting'),
(1166, 'adduction'),
(1167, 'adductions'),
(1168, 'adductive'),
(1169, 'adductor'),
(1170, 'adductors'),
(1171, 'adducts'),
(1172, 'adeem'),
(1173, 'adeemed'),
(1174, 'adeeming'),
(1175, 'adeems'),
(1176, 'adelantado'),
(1177, 'ademption'),
(1178, 'ademptions'),
(1179, 'adenectomy'),
(1180, 'adenine'),
(1181, 'adenitis'),
(1182, 'adenoid'),
(1183, 'adenoidal'),
(1184, 'adenoids'),
(1185, 'adenoma'),
(1186, 'adenomas'),
(1187, 'adenomata'),
(1188, 'adenosine'),
(1189, 'adenovirus'),
(1190, 'adept'),
(1191, 'adeptly'),
(1192, 'adeptness'),
(1193, 'adepts'),
(1194, 'adequacies'),
(1195, 'adequacy'),
(1196, 'adequate'),
(1197, 'adequately'),
(1198, 'adequative'),
(1199, 'adermin'),
(1200, 'adessive'),
(1201, 'adharma'),
(1202, 'adhere'),
(1203, 'adhered'),
(1204, 'adherence'),
(1205, 'adherences'),
(1206, 'adherent'),
(1207, 'adherents'),
(1208, 'adherer'),
(1209, 'adherers'),
(1210, 'adheres'),
(1211, 'adhering'),
(1212, 'adhesion'),
(1213, 'adhesions'),
(1214, 'adhesive'),
(1215, 'adhesively'),
(1216, 'adhesives'),
(1217, 'adhibit'),
(1218, 'adhibited'),
(1219, 'adhibiting'),
(1220, 'adhibition'),
(1221, 'adhibits'),
(1222, 'adiabatic'),
(1223, 'adiaphora'),
(1224, 'adiaphoron'),
(1225, 'adieu'),
(1226, 'adieus'),
(1227, 'adieux'),
(1228, 'adigranth'),
(1229, 'adiós'),
(1230, 'adipic'),
(1231, 'adipocere'),
(1232, 'adipose'),
(1233, 'adiposity'),
(1234, 'adit'),
(1235, 'adits'),
(1236, 'adjacency'),
(1237, 'adjacent'),
(1238, 'adjacently'),
(1239, 'adjectival'),
(1240, 'adjective'),
(1241, 'adjectives'),
(1242, 'adjoin'),
(1243, 'adjoined'),
(1244, 'adjoining'),
(1245, 'adjoins'),
(1246, 'adjoint'),
(1247, 'adjourn'),
(1248, 'adjourned'),
(1249, 'adjourning'),
(1250, 'adjourns'),
(1251, 'adjudge'),
(1252, 'adjudged'),
(1253, 'adjudges'),
(1254, 'adjudging'),
(1255, 'adjudgment'),
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has a limit of 500 records in one `INSERT` command.
Split it up.

Comment: What is the problem with that?

Comment: first of all thanks sir.
i have to insert DATA near about 2 lac so.